# Example of two sequences $ (a_n) $ and $(b_n) $ so that $\lim(a_n)=0$, $\lim(b_n)=+\infty$ and $\lim(a_n \cdot b_n)=2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I am given two sequences, $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ with limits $\lim(a_n)=0$, $\lim(b_n)=+\infty$ but the limit of the product should equal $2$.

I am confused here because I was in belief that the product of a zero-sequence and any sequence should equal a zero-sequence and this if $(c_n)=(a_n \cdot b_n) \Rightarrow \lim(c_n)=\lim(a_n \cdot b_n)$. So my question is: Is there any example of two sequences $a$ and $b$ such that it is possible to have the limit of the product = $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_n=\frac{2}{n}$ and $b_n=n$ works. It's true that $\lim a_nb_n=(\lim a_n)(\lim b_n)$ provided that the limits of $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ exist and are finite; infinite limits have to be handled more carefully.